# Invalid regular expression error in RegExp

Tags: javascript

I am using RegExp for the validation of US phone number. For ReEmailFormat6 i am getting below error:
[image]

but other expression running fine. I am not sure why I am this issue . Please find my code below:

```
    var reEmailFormat2 = new RegExp("(.)\1{7,}"); //match if phone number has same number repeated 8 or more times
var reEmailFormat3 = new RegExp("^0{1}[\d]{9}$"); //match if phone number has leading 0 with 9 digits after the 0
var reEmailFormat4 = new RegExp("1{1}[\d]{9}$"); //match if phone number has leading 1 with 9 digits after the 1
var reEmailFormat5 = new RegExp("/^[+]?(1\-|1\s|1|\d{3}\-|\d{3}\s|)?((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{4})$/g");
var reEmailFormat6 = new RegExp("^(?:\+?1[-. ]?)?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$");
debugger;

if (controlToValidate[0].value == "" || controlToValidate[0].value == controlToValidate.attr("placeholder")) {
    args.IsValid = false;
    controlToValidate.addClass("site-validation-field");
}
else if (controlToValidate[0].value == "") {
    args.IsValid = false;
    controlToValidate.addClass("site-validation-field");
}
else if ((reEmailFormat6.test(controlToValidate[0].value))) {
    debugger;
    args.IsValid = false;
    controlToValidate.addClass("site-validation-field");
}
```

Comment: You're getting the error because your regular expression is syntactically incorrect. Also, it's a bad idea to use the RegExp constructor instead of simpler regex literal syntax because you have to deal with additional quoting issues, which your code does not do properly.

Comment: And finally: this is a terrible idea, modern email addresses are basically just "anything" followed by @, followed by "anything", followed by as many "dot anything" as the world wants to slap on. Which they can. And do. And in addition: why are your vars about "email" but your comments about "phone"?

Comment: @Pointy this is the expression i am using in vb working as expected. but same in java script  giving error. I can try regex literal ..Thanks !!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans no, it's not "modern" email addresses. This has been the case for a *VERY* long time. It's just that many people completely ignored the standard when writing validations.

Comment: `+` is a meta-character in regex. To use its literal value you have to escape it (`\+`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite all of your regular expressions with regular expression literal syntax:

```
var reEmailFormat2 = /(.)\1{7,}/; //match if phone number has same number repeated 8 or more times
var reEmailFormat3 = /^0{1}[\d]{9}$/; //match if phone number has leading 0 with 9 digits after the 0
var reEmailFormat4 = /1{1}[\d]{9}$/; //match if phone number has leading 1 with 9 digits after the 1
var reEmailFormat5 = /^[+]?(1\-|1\s|1|\d{3}\-|\d{3}\s|)?((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{4})$/g;
var reEmailFormat6 = /^(?:\+?1[-. ]?)?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

When you form your regular expressions as *strings* to pass to the `RegExp()` constructor, you have to take into account the fact that the string syntax in JavaScript also uses the backslash character as a meta-character. Thus if you don't double your backslash characters in the source string, the process of parsing it as a string will **remove** them.